# variable value changing depending on what link selected PHP

Tags: php, variables, hyperlink

This is my for loop.

```
for ($i = 0; $i <= count($prod_ar) - 1; $i++) {
    $_SESSION['food'] = $prod_ar[$i];
    echo "<a href='search.php'>$prod_ar[$i]</a>" . "</br>";
}
```

It outputs this (each line is an individual link)

```
Chocolate Brownie Finger
Honey Cake
Mini Flourless Cake
Pecan Cinnamon Crumb Cake
Scone
Turkey and Cheese Sandwich
```

When i click on the link, i want the $_SESSION['food'] variable to equal/store the words of the link selected - e.g. Chocolate Brownie Finger (if it was clicked on).

This is so that it can be used in my search.php file.

How do i do this?

(Obviously at the moment the $_SESSION['food'] variable is equal to 'Turkey and Cheese Sandwich' as that is he last $prod_ar in the for loop.)

Comment: Why do you need this data in session? Simple GET request will work.

Comment: Use GET. Add ?food=$prod_ar[$i] to link href. And in search.php get this parameter by $_GET[“food”].

Comment: Is `$prod_ar` a fixed array?

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to add an additional $_GET parameter to the URL. Something like this:

`echo "<a href='search.php?food=$i'>$prod_ar[$i]</a>"."</br>";`

When the link is clicked, $_GET['food'] will be the index of the clicked link.

Answer (score 0):

Use simple GET-request (search.php?term=Honey+Cake)

```php
for ($i = 0; $i <= count($prod_ar) - 1; $i++) {
    $term = urlencode($prod_ar[$i]);
    echo "<a href='search.php?term=$term'>$prod_ar[$i]</a></br>";
}
```

In **search.php** you'll get search term as:

```
echo urldecode($_GET['term']);
```

Comment: Feel free to __accept__ the answer if it helps.